# Fill rows Excel with color in openpyxl of Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

How to fill rows with color in openpyxl, if the row number for fill is unknown in advance? It is rows of headers that go at the beginning of the sections unknown amount of data rows, e.g.:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import random
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for section in range(10):
    header_row = ('col1', 'col2')
    ws.append(header_row)   # Wanted to fill this
    random_amount_rows = [('bar', 'foo') for i in range(1, random.randrange(2,10))]
    for datarow in random_amount_rows: 
        ws.append(datarow)
```

In common cases, when the row number is known, it can be filled follows:

```
fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="DDDDDD")
for cell in list(ws.rows)[rownumber]:
    cell.fill = fill
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works as follows via write-only mode. Thanks, Charlie Clark.

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.write_only import WriteOnlyCell
fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="DDDDDD")   

for section in sections:
    row_to_fill_texts = ('col1', 'col2')
    row = []
    for h in row_to_fill_texts:
        cell = WriteOnlyCell(ws, value=h)
        cell.fill = fill
        row.append(cell)
    ws.append(row)
    # adding other lines
```

Comment: i got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.worksheet.write_only'`

Answer (score 2):

You can append cells instead of values and thus apply formatting. See the section on write-only mode in the documentation. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html#write-only-mode